# The webpage cannot be found - HTTP 404 JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web, web.xml

Experts,

My dynamic web project having 3 JSP page and 3 servlets .. and everthing was working fine till date.

when i executed the same project today, it was showing this below message.

The webpage cannot be found - HTTP 404

I deleted the whole project after trying multiple checks... now in web.xml if i remove the servlets section, its displaying the jsp content. but if i add the servlet back its throwing same page cannot be found :(

no error in project and i dont see any logs in eclipse... can someone please tel me why this is happening?
Appreciate your input. Thanks

Comment: A few general suggestions on debugging web apps:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are a few general suggestions on debugging web apps:

3 and 4 would be the first checks for 404.

1. Try to start the web app in the debug mode, and place the break point in the servlet method: any hit? (or just put a System.out.println in the Servlet);
2. Check the structure of the dynamic web project in Eclipse: are the compiled java classes of the servlets in there?
3. Check the context path (url) of the dynamic web project in eclipse project config: not accidentally changed?
4. Check the log files of the tomcat (access logs and catalina logs) your dynamic web project is associated with.

Comment: Thanks @serge for your response. I have checked the stacktrace logs and its says as below  :Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SAPTest] and further when i checked the logs it says this as well -->Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.JsonObject                                                         but i have this jar imported and class file is complied..weird not sure what is the issue:(

Comment: The jar file has to be part of the web project deployment configuration and thus be available in the web app lib directory. Project -> right click -> ... deployment configuration.-> verify the jars are in there.

Comment: Thanks Serge..I came here to tell you that i did and it worked... and you gave the same suggestions. Thanks